# WebView does not show CSS that is located internally in the project

Tags: android, html, css, kotlin, webview

I need to show a HTML content styled with a CSS file that is needed to be downloaded from an url and stored inside **"context.filesDir"**. Inside this downloaded folder there are all the assets that CSS file uses. even though I pass the path of the CSS file to my webview. Only plain html text shows.

This is the path for the so called css. I ve checked and file exists also I can see it inside Device Explorer as well.

```
File(context.filesDir.path+"/v4/v4/c/", "mobil-app.css").path
```

for my html I also create  tag inside  for stylesheet href

```
val html = "...<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///data/user/0/<package-name>/files/v4/v4/c/mobil-app.css\"/>...
```

and then I call the webview object with **.loadWithBaseURL()** method but css does not work. I tried calling it with

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null)
```

and

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///data/data/<package-name>/files/v4/v4/c/.", html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8",null)
```

but nothing changes. Can anybody help me find what am I missing here?

Comment: context.filesDir is not context.cacheDir. So please clarify.

Comment: it's my mistake I apologize. Initially I was trying with context.filesDir, then I tried "cacheDir" I believe I copied that part of the code by mistake. I have fixed it now

Comment: That is not the url of a file in the last load data. There is nothing like a file name like index.html.

Comment: And did you try loadUrl() ,?

Comment: No I have not tried loadUrl() and I do not have html file because I am passing html string to my webview object @blackapps

Comment: Ok. But now you pass a directory. I doubt if that is ok.

Comment: So what should I do in order to apply the internally stored css to a html string that is loaded on a webview? @blackapps

Comment: Dont know. Post the smallest possible html source. And the smallest possible css file then i will test when time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve the issue. Turns out when I was calling loadDataWithBaseUrl method for the baseUrl the path I was passing was wrong. After I figured it out the html content was styled with the css file.